# QML Render the same Entity in two Scene3Ds

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

How can I insert the same entity to be displayed into more than one `Scene3D`s in QML?

(it'll probably be abundantly clear that I'm pretty new to QML)

I would like to create something similar to the [Multi Viewport QML Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-multiviewport-example.html), except I would like to have the viewports in differet layouts (e.g. a [SplitView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html)).

Ultimately I would like my entities (`Mesh` or `SceneLoader` entities) to be created completely outside of my views (my `Scene3D`), and be able to show the same data in multiple views without having copies.

I haven't had much luck putting a `Layout` into a `Scene3D`, and even so, that would constrain me against having the same data show up elsewhere.  I simply can't figure out how to define my data outside the views, especially since I can't figure out how to append to the `components`/`data`/`children` properties.

For example, in the (long) example below, I figured out how to define `torusMesh2` outside of the `Scene3D` by setting it's `.parent` to inject it into `scene3DRightEntity`, but I cannot figure out how to inject it into both `Scene3D`s

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.0

import Qt3D.Extras 2.0
Item {

    Button {
        text: 'Button'
        onClicked: {
            console.log('Button clicked');
        }
    }


    SphereMesh {
        id: torusMesh2; radius: 5
        parent: scene3DRightEntity
    }
    PhongMaterial { id: material2; parent: scene3DRightEntity }
    Transform { id: torusTransform2; scale3D: Qt.vector3d(1.5, 1, 0.5); rotation: fromAxisAndAngle(Qt.vector3d(1, 0, 0), 45); parent: scene3DRightEntity }


    Rectangle {
        id: topRect
        anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 50

        color: 'green'

        SplitView {
            anchors.fill: parent; orientation: Qt.Horizontal

            Rectangle {
                id: scene
                anchors.margins: 50; width: 200; Layout.minimumWidth: 100; Layout.maximumWidth: 500
                color: "darkRed"

                Text { text: "View 1"; anchors.centerIn: parent }

                Scene3D {
                    id: scene3dLeft
                    anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 10; focus: true
                    aspects: ["input", "logic"]
                    cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

                    Entity {

                        SimpleCamera {
                            id: camera1; fieldOfView: 45; position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 40.0 )
                        }

                        components: [
                            RenderSettings {
                                activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                                    camera: camera1.camera
                                    clearColor: "transparent"
                                }
                            }
                            , InputSettings { }
                        ]

                        TorusMesh {
                            id: torusMesh1; radius: 5; minorRadius: 1; rings: 100; slices: 20
                        }
                        PhongMaterial { id: material1 }
                        Transform { id: torusTransform1; scale3D: Qt.vector3d(1.5, 1, 0.5); rotation: fromAxisAndAngle(Qt.vector3d(1, 0, 0), 45) }

                        Entity {
                            id: torusEntity1
                            components: [ torusMesh1, material1, torusTransform1 ]
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            Rectangle {
                id: scene2
                Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.minimumWidth: 50; Layout.maximumWidth: 400; height: 300
                color: "darkBlue"

                Scene3D {
                    id: scene3dRight
                    anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 50; focus: true;
                    aspects: ["input", "logic"]
                    cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

                    Entity {
                        id: scene3DRightEntity
                        SimpleCamera {
                            id: camera2
                            position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 40.0 )
                        }

                        components: [
                            RenderSettings {
                                activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                                    camera: camera2.camera
                                    clearColor: "transparent"
                                }
                            }
                            , InputSettings { }
                        ]

                        Entity {
                            id: torusEntity2
                            components: [ torusMesh2, material2, torusTransform2 ]
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

} // Item
```

**UPDATE**

My first post was creating `torusMesh2` as a child of the `SplitView`, this edit moves it to the top of the tree and sets its `.parent`.